# How to define category in yapsy plugin?

Tags: python, plugins

I use yapsy in this struct:

```
script.py
plugins
 |-equipments
 | |-eq1.py
 | |-eq1.yapsy-plugin
 |-tasks
   |-tsk1.py
   |-tsk1.yapsy-plugin
```

script.py

```python
from yapsy.PluginManager import PluginManager

# Load the plugins from the plugin directory.
manager = PluginManager()
manager.setPluginPlaces(["plugins"])
manager.collectPlugins()

# Loop round the plugins and initialization.
for plugin in manager.getAllPlugins():
    print plugin.plugin_object.init_plugin()
    print plugin.path
    print plugin.category
```

It works fine. But how to make plugins in various directory have different categories?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Categories in yapsy are not detected by directories but via the class inherited by each plugin instance.

For instance, with your application, you could have your "equipment" plugins inherit an `IEquipementPlugin` class, and your "task" plugins inherit an `ITaskPlugin` .

Then, when configuring your plugin manager, it's just a matter of giving a mapping between your categories' names and their respective base classes:

```
# Define the various categories corresponding to the different
# kinds of plugins you have defined
manager.setCategoriesFilter({
   "Equipement" : IEquipementPlugin,
   "Task" : ITaskPlugin,
   })
```

Please **be aware of a caveat** that makes it hasardous to have one of your categories be defined by a child class of a class defining another category (the plugin manager will be confused), see [related question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6986563/yapsy-doesnt-load-plugin-correctly) and the [corresponding bug report](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3467746&group_id=208383&atid=1005476).

See also on yapsy's documentation: http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/#more-sophisticated-plugin-classes.

I know Yapsy's documentation is still poor on the example side of things[1], but there are working examples of plugin categories in the unit-tests.

There are also examples of categories in some real-life project out there. For instance in mathbench: http://mathbench.sourceforge.net/ (yapsy was originally designed as a subcomponent of it) and other projects listed on yapsy's documentation, see http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/index.html#brief-history

[1]: Sorry for that, I don't have much time for it but I try to incrementally improve yapsy and its doc by taking into account user feedback like yours.